# Incrementing a List Index of a Nonexistent Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to iterate through the rows of a dataset, and increment an index of a newly created list. I am aware that I am currently trying to increment a nonexistent index, but I would really appreciate any assistance trying to accomplish something similar.

Here is my code snippet:

```
attack_year_type = []
year_type_counter = []
for _, event in main_df.iterrows():
   attack_year_type.append((event['iyear'], event['attacktype1_txt']))
   year_type_counter[int(event['iyear'])][event['attacktype1_txt']] += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're better off with `year_type_counter` being a `dict` of `dict`s.  And in that case, you can use `defaultdict` to accomplish what you'd like.

```
from collections import defaultdict

year_type_counter = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
attack_year_type = []

for _, event in main_df.iterrows():
    attack_year_type.append((event['iyear'], event['attacktype1_txt']))
    year_type_counter[int(event['iyear'])][event['attacktype1_txt']] += 1
```

Comment: Seems to work very well. Can you just explain why you used a lambda instead of just using defaultdict(defaultdict(int)) ?

Comment: `defaultdict` takes a `callable` and `defaultdict(int)` is **not** a callable.  So I wrap it in a `lambda` which makes it a `callable`

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is you can initialize the lists as shown below

```
attack_year_type = [None]*(main_df.count())
year_type_counter = [None]*(main_df.count())
```

and then, modify the elements based on the index.